# Javascript: Any reason to use 2 seperate arrays for key value pairs over a hashtable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, key-value

I saw some code which was storing key,value pairs in 2 arrays. The only purpose of this storage was to use the 2 arrays as a hashtable, 1 array stored keys, the other values. Is there any performance advantage to doing this?

This particular example consisted of 2 arrays of strings.. e.g

```
q[0] = "key" v[0] = "value"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Hashing the key is not a very expensive operation. Certainly not to an extent that justifies the unsightly mess that would be required to make this sample work as a real hashtable substitute.

Comment: Is there any performance decrease using a hashtable of this godawful sight?

Comment: No. You'd have to iterate over each element of the key table to find what you're looking for. Proper hashtables tend to go for an algorithm which generates a reproducible location or at least a starting point for one. Read a basic Computer Science textbook on data structures to see why this would become problematic in a very large hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript pretty much are hashtables that limit their keys to being integers. They are not "true" arrays that are contiguous slabs of memory that are accessed by an offset (index) like they are in most languages. My guess is the original author assumed an array in JavaScript is implemented in the classical sense.

So this is essentially twice as inefficient as just doing `q["key"] = "value"` and making q an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it *could* be be merely a preference, but it's been idiomatic for many years. In C, for example, an array has a type and it's more difficult to have an array of varying types (i.e., array[key0], array[value0], array[key1], array[value1]) than simply to have the keys and values in different arrays. For me, it would be a nightmare having keys and values in the same array because I'd always have to remember to double any index into that array and then, for the value, to increment it. Too much for my lazy brain.